# Problem Scraping Element & Child Text with lxml & etree

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to scrape lists from Wikipedia pages (like this one for example: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Bisch%C3%B6fe_von_Sk%C3%A1lholt) in a particular format. I am encountering issues getting 'li' and 'a href' to match up.

For example, from the above page, the ninth bullet has text:

*1238–1268: Sigvarður Þéttmarsson (Norweger)*

with HTML:

```
 <li>1238–1268: <a href="/wiki/Sigvar%C3%B0ur_%C3%9E%C3%A9ttmarsson" title="Sigvarður Þéttmarsson">Sigvarður Þéttmarsson</a> (Norweger)</li>
```

I want to pull it together as a dictionary:

'1238–1268: Sigvarður Þéttmarsson (Norweger)': '/wiki/Sigvar%C3%B0ur_%C3%9E%C3%A9ttmarsson'

[Entire text of both parts of 'li' and 'a' child]: [href of 'a' child]

I know I can use lxml/etree to do this, but I'm not entirely sure how. Some recombination of the below?

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(html)

bishops = tree.cssselect('li').text for bishop
text = [li.text for li in bishops]

links = tree.cssselect('li a')
hrefs = [bishop.get('href') for bishop in links]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have figured this out using BeautifulSoup as follows:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 html = driver.page_source
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

 bishops_with_links = {}
 bishops = soup.select('li')

 for bishop in bishops:
     if bishop.findChildren('a'):
         bishops_with_links[bishop.text] = 'https://de.wikipedia.org' + bishop.a.get('href')
     else:
         bishops_with_links[bishop.text] = ''
 return bishops_with_links
```